# Changing background picture with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following idea:
 container contains some info and I would like to change the div icon with another picture with .hover event. Here is my div container.

```
<div class="column1">
         <span class="columnLogo"></span>
         <span class="fTitle"><h5>Front-end Development</h5>
            <img src="images/mini1.png"></span>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    </div>
```

I need to change the image of the first `<span>` element while hovering the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS with background-images for this. Use HTML such as:

```
<div class="column1">
     <span class="columnLogo"></span>
     <span class="fTitle"><h5>Front-end Development</h5><img src="images/mini1.png"></span>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
</div>
```

And CSS such as:

```
.column1 .columnLogo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat center;
}
.column1:hover .columnLogo {
    background-image: url(images/logo-hover.png);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I select multiple classes before :hover? Like .column1, column2:hover?

Comment: Yes - but you have to include :hover on each one, and remember the `.` - such as: `.column1:hover, .column2:hover`

Answer (score 2):

```
.column1:hover{
   background: #f0f0f0 url('my-image.jpg');
}
```

Comment: This is how I select the column, but i need to change the image of the first <span> element while hovering the column. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: if you can work with css, is the best way.. you can set image to background of container div.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(".column1 img")
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You may transform the img in span with background mini1.png and with css control de hover of that span.

```
    <div class="column1">
     <span class="columnLogo"></span>
     <span class="fTitle"><h5>Front-end Development</h5>
        <span class="myimageclass">&nbsp;</span>

      </span>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
</div>
```

css:

```
   .myimageclass{background:url("images/mini1.png");}
   .myimageclass:hover {background:url("images/mini2.png");}
```